# what's nested classes shown in classes explorer in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

My intellij/Android Studio shows me the following:

[image]

1. What does it me that `LoadArticleThread` is nested within `LoadTextsListThread.java` ?
2. What does locker mean drawn near some of classes names and gray circle near the nested one?

Comment: 1/ that's because the class is not named like the file (I think) 2/ means the class is public

Comment: see also https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html

Comment: @RC., thanks, 2nd is clear :). I didn't get the first one, can you please clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have a non-public class named *LoadArticleThread* inside a file named *LoadTextsListThread*. The file name does not match the class name.
2. green lock: class is public
   grey circle: class is package-private (no acces modifier)
   grey key: class is protected